# Custom Primary Key with a fixed number at the beginning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm looking for a solution for my little problem.

I want a Primary Key with a fixed number and a auto increment number.

Like:

```
KEY
```

- 513_1
- 513_2
- 513_3
- 513_4
- 513_5

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why don't you use a normal primary key and prepend `513_` where you need it?

Comment: Or possibly even better (more flexible for later), two columns, one to hold the prefix and the other to auto increment.  Make a composite key.  Deal with the concatenation in your app.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter:                                                UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET PrimaryKeyColumn = CONCAT('513_', PrimaryKeyColumn) 
WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn NOT LIKE '513_%';

Comment: @Denis1893: no, why you are modifying this column at all? What's so important at the constant `513_` which just wastes storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at persistent computed columns. Use a identity column add another value and viola you can achieve this.

Comment: When I have an ID column and a KEY column. Is it possible to create a computed column with these two columns and add the computed column as primary key? See @sarin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A Primary Key should uniquely identify a row and controversially shouldn't hold any domain meaning itself.

Create a new column on your table which you can related your rows together e.g.

```
ID   KEY
1    513
2    513
3    513
4    513
5    513
```